# Multiple items slick slider stacking issue on loading

Tags: slider, slick.js

I am using multiple item slick slider. It's creating stacking slides disturbance while loading as shown in the picture below. Can anyone help me how to avoid this disturbance while loading. Thanks in advance :)

[Stacked slides on loading image][1]

*Javascript *

```
  $('.sopeo-now-sm-pills').slick({
     slidesToShow: 3,
     slidesToScroll: 1,   
     arrows: true,
     swipeToSlide:true   
    });
```

*html*

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills sopeo-now-sm-pills" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link active" href="#now-adm-module" data-toggle="pill">                            
                       <div class="sopeo-now-icon">
                          <i class="fas fa-bed"></i>
                       </div>      
                       <div class="module-text">Admissions</div>                       
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#now-dis-module" data-toggle="pill">                           
                        <div class="sopeo-now-icon">
                            <i class="fas fa-suitcase-rolling"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="module-text">Discharge</div>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#now-ae-module" data-toggle="pill">                            
                          <div class="sopeo-now-icon">
                          <i class="fas fa-ambulance"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="module-text">A&E</div>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#now-facilities-module" data-toggle="pill">                            
                        <div class="sopeo-now-icon">
                          <i class="fas fa-broom"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div class="module-text">Facilities</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#now-pharmacy-module" data-toggle="pill">                           
                        <div class="sopeo-now-icon">
                          <i class="fas fa-pills"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div class="module-text">Pharmacy</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#now-radiology-module" data-toggle="pill">                           
                        <div class="sopeo-now-icon">
                            <i class="fas fa-x-ray"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div class="module-text">Radiology</div></a>
                    </li>                      
                  </ul>
```

Comment: This can usually be avoided with one line of CSS: `.sopeo-now-sm-pills:not(.slick-initialized) { display: none !important; }` - the idea being the carousel is hidden until it's been given the `.slick-initialized` class by Slick itself.

Comment: I did the same. Thank you :)